# How to change column header text size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using `DataGrid` and I want to change the column header text size (for example here name should be 20 pix)

how can I do that?

I was tried with something as follows but i didnt find the highet

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column5}" Header="Name"  Width="*" />
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridTextColumn">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="True">
                        <!--<Setter Property="HeaderStyle" Value= />-->
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column5}" Header="Name"  Width="*" />
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

For Column Header, the style need to be targeted for `DataGridColumnHeader`... Read [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/1fa7a4a1-cc51-4005-8d32-54dd4963818c/datagrid-column-header-style?forum=silverlightcontrols)